# ADB shell "vi" file and command issue

Tags: adb, shell, command-line

I don't know how to fix the following issue, please help me (My OS is Win 10):

After I use adb shell to enter the device->

1. When I use "tab", it shows some symbols (it may related to the next issue)

[image]

2. I try to edit the file. but as you can see, its format is complete chaos

[image]

The last one is I type "space" and it keeps showing 1H/2H/3H...etc.

Am I missing additional plugins on my Windows or anything else?

I'm new to Android development, I try to find similar issues, but I have no idea what I'm looking for and how to fix this one.

Feel free to give any advice! Thanks!

Comment: What `vi` version do you use? Android by default does not contain an editor like vi or nano. So may be your vi version expects a different environment (linux terminal). The output window looks like old Windows `cmd` terminal. You can check is Powershell is better for starting `adb shell`.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I have a feeling the formatting issue is due to [the different new line indicators between Unix (LF) and Windows (CRLF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552749/2821954)...

Comment: Please dont use images for textual information.

Comment: Rather than using `vi`, start by using `cat` on the file, and see if that produces saner output. Please update the question with the results.